# Can I Inner Join 2 tables based on multiple values for a column

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is what I want,

```
TableA Inner Join TableB 
      on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA OR TableB.ColumnA = NULL
```

It gives no results back, any alternative ?

Edit

[image]

Comment: "not working" is not a valid issue description. Can you please describe your problem clearly? List out table schema, expected results, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in your query is `TableB.ColumnA = NULL`.

`NULL` is undefined and you cannot use comparison operators to check null.

Replace

```
TableB.ColumnA = NULL
```

With

```
TableB.ColumnA IS NULL
```

By looking at the picture description, I think you are looking for a `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: I was not looking for LEFT JOIN, but problem was with "= NULL", I am using Inner Join with condition for getting null values from table B, thanks for your help

Comment: I was bit confused with your expected results. Glad to hear you have sorted the issue..